# Apache Mod-rewrite: How to write search engine friendly URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Basically I have seen some examples on this forum however mine is pretty straight forward and I havent been able to locate just my case.

1) I need to change this url: domain.com/page.php to domain.com/page
2) I need to change this url: domain.com/page.php?ID=1 to domain.com/page/1 -> 1 being any number between 1 and infinity

All this running on Apache server.

Thanks,

---

**Update**
Any one has any idea? I feel I am so close to getting this working. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use a regex based rule...

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Thanks Jlujan, I am not sure I quiet understood that. I wrote: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1

Unfortunately I am getting no joy ;-(

Comment: Actually if I type in the rewritten URL it works fine. When I navigate on my site, the "clean" URL is not displayed. [link]http://mantlo.com/detail.php?property=2 works fine. So does [link]http://mantlo.com/property/2/. The second URL does not automatically show. The code in my .htaccess file: RewriteRule ^property/([0-9]+)/?$ detail.php?property=$1 [NC] # Handle property requests.